# Peculiar warnings at C

Tags: c, warnings

In my project I have these 2 files. When I try to compile it a get some peculiar warnings that I cannot solve, though my program runs fine. I use the -Wall and -Wextra arguments at compile.

```
//File: DataStructures.h 
     typedef struct EntryListPacketStruct EntryListPacket;
        typedef struct IndexesPacketStruct IndexesPacket;
        typedef struct MatchingQueriesResultStruct MatchingQueriesResult;
        typedef struct DataPacketStruct* DataPacketPtr;

        extern DataPacketPtr Packet;

        EntryListPacket* allocateEntryListPacket(void);

        void initializeDataPacket(DataPacketPtr);
        void freeDataPacket(DataPacketPtr);

        void initializeEntryListPacket(EntryListPacket*);
        void freeEntryListsPacket(EntryListPacket*);
```

I include the DataStructures.h in the following file:

```
//File: DataStructures.c
 struct EntryListPacketStruct {
        EntryList* exactTypeEntryList;
        EntryList** editDistEntryLists;
        EntryList** hammingDistEntryLists;
    };

    struct DataPacketStruct {
        struct EntryListPacket* entryLists;
        struct IndexesPacket* indexes;
        dllistptr matchingQResultList;
    };

EntryListPacket* allocateEntryListPacket(void){
    EntryListPacket* temp=malloc(sizeof(EntryListPacket));
    return temp;
}

 void initializeDataPacket(DataPacketPtr packet){
     DataPacketPtr temp;

     temp=malloc(sizeof(struct DataPacketStruct));

     initializeEntryListPacket(temp->entryLists);

     initializeIndexesPacket(temp->indexes);

     packet=temp;
 }

 void freeDataPacket(DataPacketPtr packet){

     freeEntryListsPacket(packet->entryLists);
     freeIndexesPacket(packet->indexes);
     free(packet);
 }

void initializeEntryListPacket(EntryListPacket* packet) {

    packet->exactTypeEntryList = NULL;

    packet->editDistEntryLists = malloc(sizeof (EntryList)*22);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        packet->editDistEntryLists[i] = NULL;
    }


    packet->hammingDistEntryLists = malloc(sizeof (EntryList)*27);
    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        packet->hammingDistEntryLists[i] = NULL;
    }
}

 void freeEntryListsPacket(EntryListPacket* packet){
     if(packet->exactTypeEntryList!=NULL)
        DestroyEntryList(packet->exactTypeEntryList);
     free(packet->exactTypeEntryList);

     int i;
     for(i=0;i<22;i++){
         if(packet->editDistEntryLists[i]!=NULL){  
              printf("%d\n",i); 
             DestroyEntryList(packet->editDistEntryLists[i]);

         }
         free(packet->editDistEntryLists[i]);       
     }
     free(packet->editDistEntryLists);

     for(i=0;i<27;i++){
         if(packet->hammingDistEntryLists[i]!=NULL){      
              printf("%d\n",i); 
             DestroyEntryList(packet->hammingDistEntryLists[i]);              
         }
         free(packet->hammingDistEntryLists[i]);   
     }
     free(packet->hammingDistEntryLists);
     free(packet);   
 }
```

//File:main.c

```
EntryListPacket *temp;
    temp=allocateEntryListPacket();
    initializeEntryListPacket(temp);

    freeEntryListsPacket(temp);
```

And I get the following Warnings:

```
 DataStructures.c: In function ‘initializeDataPacket’:
    DataStructures.c:48:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘initializeEntryListPacket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
          initializeEntryListPacket(temp->entryLists);
          ^
    In file included from DataStructures.c:6:0:
    DataStructures.h:27:10: note: expected ‘struct EntryListPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct EntryListPacket *’
         void initializeEntryListPacket(EntryListPacket*);
              ^
    DataStructures.c:50:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘initializeIndexesPacket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
          initializeIndexesPacket(temp->indexes);
          ^
    In file included from DataStructures.c:6:0:
    DataStructures.h:30:10: note: expected ‘struct IndexesPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct IndexesPacket *’
         void initializeIndexesPacket(IndexesPacket*);
              ^
    DataStructures.c:43:42: warning: parameter ‘packet’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
      void initializeDataPacket(DataPacketPtr packet){
                                              ^
    DataStructures.c: In function ‘freeDataPacket’:
    DataStructures.c:57:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘freeEntryListsPacket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
          freeEntryListsPacket(packet->entryLists);
          ^
    In file included from DataStructures.c:6:0:
    DataStructures.h:28:10: note: expected ‘struct EntryListPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct EntryListPacket *’
         void freeEntryListsPacket(EntryListPacket*);
              ^
    DataStructures.c:58:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘freeIndexesPacket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
          freeIndexesPacket(packet->indexes);
          ^
    In file included from DataStructures.c:6:0:
    DataStructures.h:31:10: note: expected ‘struct IndexesPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct IndexesPacket *’
         void freeIndexesPacket(IndexesPacket*);
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong or if the compiler is stuck since this for example: `DataStructures.h:28:10: note: expected ‘struct EntryListPacket *’ but argument is of type ‘struct EntryListPacket *’`
doesn't seem reasonable to me. 
Thx in advance!

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: How are u calling those functions?

Comment: @arunb2w I will edit the post to answer your question

Comment: Lost in `typedef`s again ... ;-) Nice error message your provoked however!

Comment: Does your `.c` file include the `.h` file?

Comment: @pat ofcourse it does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DataStructures.h`, try replacing this:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    struct EntryListPacket* entryLists;
    ...
```

With this:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    EntryListPacket* entryLists;
    ...
```

Or this:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    struct EntryListPacketStruct* entryLists;
    ...
```

And similarly for `struct IndexesPacket* indexes;`. The compiler warning comes from missing the `typedef` symbol up with the `struct` symbol itself.

Comment: Same issue for `struct IndexesPacket* indexes;`.

Comment: @mbratch yes this solves my issues, but why they occurred? Since I typedef the structs doesn't the compiler know that they are the same thing?

Comment: As per your declarations, this `struct EntryListPacket* entryLists;` would somehow result in `struct struct EntryListPacketStruct * entryLists;`.

Comment: @Mario technically they are the same but not syntactically. You have either `struct EntryListPacketStruct` or `EntryListPacket` which is typedef'ed as `struct EntryListPacketStruct`. The compiler is forgiving enough to allow you to say `struct EntryListPacket` but it isn't syntactically precise enough to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct` tags include a `Struct` suffix, but you omitted it when you declared:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    struct EntryListPacket* entryLists;
    struct IndexesPacket* indexes;
    dllistptr matchingQResultList;
};
```

It should be:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    struct EntryListPacketStruct* entryLists;
    struct IndexesPacketStruct* indexes;
    dllistptr matchingQResultList;
};
```

Or just:

```
struct DataPacketStruct {
    EntryListPacket* entryLists;
    IndexesPacket* indexes;
    dllistptr matchingQResultList;
};
```

Also, your `initializeDataPacket` function is leaking the memory.  Assigning `temp` to `packet` doesn't return the value since `packet` is passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: Actually, the calls to `initializeEntryListPacket` and `initializeIndexesPacket` from `initializeDataPacket` are most likely going to cause a crash, since you are dereferencing pointers that have never been initialized in the newly allocated `DataPacketStruct`